# Why 't' and 'f' instead of TRUE and FALSE

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, psql

**Why does PostgreSQL return 't' and 'f' instead of TRUE and FALSE?**

The [documentation itself](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-boolean.html) advises us to use TRUE and FALSE when inserting boolean values or making comparisons, but returns a different set of values when selecting the value from the database.

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (a boolean, b text);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (TRUE, 'sic est');
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (FALSE, 'non est');
SELECT * FROM test1;
 a |    b
---+---------
 t | sic est
 f | non est
```

Is there a reason for this behavior? Have the PostgreSQL commmunity ever tried to change that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not return these instead of boolean values.  It is some clients (for example, `psql` and pgAdminIII) which represents `TRUE` with `t` and `FALSE` with `f` - try the same query in another client and you will see something else.  See, for example, what [DBVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/) gives you:

[image]

I guess the reason for showing `t` and `f` is simply sparing space in a command-line client that lacks horizontal scrolling abilities.

Note: I am in no way affiliated to DbVis Software.

Comment: Still postgres returns `t` or `f` if the query has asked its results in text mode, as for instance `psql` does. It also returns the OID of the column's datatype, so the client knows it's a boolean so it can translate/localize the value.

Answer (score 3):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

`TRUE` and `FALSE` as cited in the question context are keywords, not values that can be returned to a client. If `true` as a value was returned that would be 4 times bigger than `t`, so that's not better.

Statistically `1` and `0` are often present as numbers so they would be harder to distinguish. OTOH `t` or `f` is a strong visual hint that we have a `Boolean`. Same as `Y` and `N` in a `char` column.

`boolean` is neither [`binary`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-binary.html) nor a [`bitstring`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-bit.html). `boolean` is `boolean` and operates with a *ternary* logic around the values `true`, `false` and `null`.

Some other RDBMS lack a proper implementation, which may add to the confusion. If you want `0` and `1` instead, just cast the `boolean` to `integer` e.g. `SELECT true::int`.

[Related update in Postgres 9.5:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/release-9-5.html#AEN125383)

> - Use assignment cast behavior for data type conversions in PL/pgSQL assignments, rather than converting to and from text (Tom Lane)
>
> This change causes conversions of Booleans to strings to produce true or false, not t or f. Other type conversions may succeed in more cases than before; for example, assigning a numeric value 3.9 to an integer variable will now assign 4 rather than failing. If no assignment-grade cast is defined for the particular source and destination types, PL/pgSQL will fall back to its old I/O conversion behavior.